# Heuristic to filter out extra clicks sent by defective mice

Tags: click, mouse, hardware, double-click

It's a somewhat common issue that mice develop a defect where some of their single clicks register as two or more clicks ([reference1](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/my-mouse-sporadically-double-clicks-when-i-press-it-only-once/), [reference2](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/03/22/fix-mouse-double-clicking-when-you-click-once/), [reference 3](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Mouse-Double-Clicks-when-I-only-Single-Click/td-p/243999/page/2)).

Where I work this happens rarely, and if it does happen such mice get destroyed with extreme prejudice - so I don't have a working sample at hand. Since I work on a trading application where the difference between one click (buy 1000 contracts) and two clicks (buy 2000 contracts) is relatively important, I was wondering if someone has experience with working heuristics to

- reject obviously false clicks
- log suspicious clicks and make the user aware of the possible issue

I think this question is independent of the OS, but I'm currently using a Windows 7 environment.

Answer (score 0):

We did just find another defective mouse (from a renowned Swiss brand). The speed at which the 2 click events were logged was 14 ms. We've also found out that a human can make 2 clicks in about 150ms.

The heuristic we now use is reject the second click when faster than 32 ms (32 ms = > 2 clock ticks), and alert the user when faster than 90 ms.

We tested clicking as many times fast as we can as well as double clicking, and looked at the times between the individual clicks. All except 2 clicks were more than 100ms apart, with one being more than 90 ms, and the other being 50ms. All clicks in the double click test were 100-180ms. These numbers are not really scientific and they will probably change somewhat with different humans and mice.